# Panel Class Not working, i am missing something?

Tags: c#, panel

I am trying to get DoubleBuffered, and i don´t think it´s working.
I know Many have made this topic, but my question isn´t excatly the same, hence why i make it as i haven´t found anything on it.

So i have made a class at the bottom of my Form class,

```
public class MyDisplay : Panel
{
    public MyDisplay() :base()
    {
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;

        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint |
          ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
          ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw |
          ControlStyles.ContainerControl |
          ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
          ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor
          , true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
        this.UpdateStyles();
    }
}
```

Then at the top i have added:

```
private MyDisplay panelm = new MyDisplay();
```

And then i want to display a background:

```
panelm.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(reader.ReadBytes(reader.ReadInt32())));
```

And it doesn´t work.
I am probably missing something.
I have tried changing the size of it , i have set it to like 600x480, but nothing happens.

Not sure why.

Comment: How do you know the `DoubleBuffering` is not working?

Comment: Well, i know that the image isn´t displaying, that´s all;S

Comment: and the image works fine without `DoubleBuffering` ?

Comment: No, but i think i get where you are getting, will fix my topic:)